# How to pass variable name and value from jython to batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, websphere, jython

I want to pass variable name and value from jython script to batch file. Also, how can i access it in batch file.

In my case i want to pass varaible name and value of  "bootstrapport" and "defaulthostport " to a batch file Deploy.bat .

**ports.jy**

```
- 

      servers = AdminConfig.list( 'ServerEntry' ).splitlines() for server
        in servers : print '\n' print "Server Name : " +
       server[0:server.find('(')] print "=" *30 NamedEndPoints =
        AdminConfig.list( "NamedEndPoint" , server).splitlines() 
      for namedEndPoint in NamedEndPoints: endPointName =
       AdminConfig.showAttribute(namedEndPoint, "endPointName" ) 
    if endPointName == "BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS": 
    bootstrapendPoint = AdminConfig.showAttribute(namedEndPoint, "endPoint" ) 
    host = AdminConfig.showAttribute(bootstrapendPoint, "host" ) 
    bootstrapport = AdminConfig.showAttribute(bootstrapendPoint, "port" ) 
    print "Endpoint Name : " + endPointName + " Host : " + host + " port : " +
               bootstrapport

     elif endPointName == "WC_defaulthost":
    defaulthostendPoint = AdminConfig.showAttribute(namedEndPoint,"endPoint" ) 
    host = AdminConfig.showAttribute(defaulthostendPoint,"host" )
     defaulthostport =AdminConfig.showAttribute(defaulthostendPoint, "port" ) 
    print "Endpoint Name : " + endPointName + " Host : " + host + " port : " +
               defaulthostport

        ========================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this probem

Printed the jython result in text file then read the varaible value from text file to batch file and then delete the text file.

BATCH FILE

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (Output) do set EMULATOR_PORT=%%x
echo EMULATOR_PORT %EMULATOR_PORT%
set "BOOTSTRAP_PORT="
for /f "skip=5 delims=" %%a in (Output) do if not defined BOOTSTRAP_PORT set BOOTSTRAP_PORT=%%a
del Output
```